# Disable offline mode and rerun the build

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'customerapp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.  
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3.  
     Required by:  
         project :  
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3 available for offline mode.  
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3 available for offline mode.  
   > Could not resolve com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5.  
     Required by:  
         project :  
      > No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5 available for offline mode.  
      > No cached version of com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5 available for offline mode.  
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3.  
     Required by:  
         project : > com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2  
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3 available for offline mode.  
      > No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3 available for offline mode.  
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.  
     Required by:  
         project : > com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2  
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71 available for offline mode.  
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71 available for offline mode.  
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71.  
     Required by:  
         project : > io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:7.0.0 > io.realm:realm-transformer:7.0.0  
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71 available for offline mode.  
      > No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.71 available for offline mode.  

Possible solution:
 - Disable offline mode and rerun the build
```

Already checked and applied these answers:-

1. [No cached version of com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.2.0-alpha18-4804415 available for offline mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934109/no-cached-version-of-com-android-tools-buildaapt23-2-0-alpha18-4804415-availab)
2. [enable & disable Gradle offline mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157953/enable-disable-gradle-offline-mode)
3. [enable/disable offline mode in andriod studio 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62719726/enable-disable-offline-mode-in-andriod-studio-4-0)
4. [Gradle not searching dependencies online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203682/gradle-not-searching-dependencies-online)

Comment: simply try File-> Invalidate cached / Restart

Comment: Try to delete the  .idea and .gradle file under the project first, then reopen the project.

Comment: @D_K already done that but no luck

Comment: @Anna done that too but no luck

Comment: you are using offline version of android studio thats why its shows that error.connect wifi to your computer, close the android studio and open it again and post your gradle.build file

Comment: @D_K i am using direct wifi cable, secondly i already checked in settings of android studio that my connection is successful, thirdly i even toggled on my gradle, still error saying to disable the gradle.

Comment: did you tried View->Tool Window->gradle-> Toggle offline Mode(icon)

Comment: @D_K it's the only way in current version, yes i did toggle that icon

Answer (score 4):

Disable Offline Mode

View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar.

Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. This is solution that worked for me (Android Studion 4.1.1):

1. As Rodrigo said in the answer above above, go to View > Tool Windows > Gradle
2. Right click on the project in Gradle tab and select "**Refresh Gradle Dependencies**" [image]

3. Clean / Rebuild if needed. You may also need to Invalidate cache and restart android studio (File -> Invalidate cache / restart).